# When we need to use surrogate classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, oop, soap

I am working on a E-commerce system. I use entity framework in my data layer. You can see my request-response cycle in the picture below. In my business layer, classes are page-based. I mean, business classes are created according to the requirement of page.

- Do I need surrogate classes? I don't hide any fields of entities and only one entity's fields appears in large quantities.
- Will surrogate classes help me to improve response time?
- One more question. Should I use WCF in this case? I use WebService in my application.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your 3 questions:

1. No, doesn't sound like it.
2. No, a surrogate is used to change type serialisation.
3. Depends on your requirements.

You should structure your business logic based on the logic itself and it's complexity, not necessarily a class per page. This is not necessarily bad if it makes sense.

It's hard to give you advise based on that abstract and high level diagram. What does your code look like?

`WCF` can provide a web service. You can use `WCF` if you want to. What kind of Web Service have you currently got?

I assume you mean [Data Contract Surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx)

> Use if you need to change how a type is serialised.